# Интеграция ЮКассы в телеграм бота через вебхук

Tags: python-telegram-bot

У меня есть телеграм бот. Понадобилось добавить в него ЮКассу для приема платежей. Необходимо все это реализовать через вебхук (yookassa.Webhook). Не знаю как все это настроить. То есть мой бот принимает update телеграмма, при этом я хочу еще принимать уведомления от юкассы и реагироваь на них.
В классе бота есть функция запускающая все приложение:

```
    def run(self):
        application = ApplicationBuilder() \
            .token(self.config['token']) \
            .proxy_url(self.config['proxy']) \
            .get_updates_proxy_url(self.config['proxy']) \
            .post_init(self.post_init) \
            .concurrent_updates(True) \
            .build()

        application.add_handler(CommandHandler('reset', self.reset))
        application.add_handler(CommandHandler('help', self.help))
        application.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', self.start))

        application.add_handler(CommandHandler('add_tokens', self.add_tokens))
        application.add_handler(CommandHandler('give_sub', self.give_sub))
        application.add_handler(CommandHandler('find_user', self.find_user))
        application.add_handler(CommandHandler('change_n', self.change_n))


        application.add_handler(MessageHandler(
            filters.PHOTO | filters.Document.IMAGE,
            self.vision))
        application.add_handler(MessageHandler(
            filters.AUDIO | filters.VOICE | filters.Document.AUDIO |
            filters.VIDEO | filters.VIDEO_NOTE | filters.Document.VIDEO,
            self.transcribe))
        application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & (~filters.COMMAND), self.text_handler))
        application.add_handler(InlineQueryHandler(self.inline_query, chat_types=[
            constants.ChatType.GROUP, constants.ChatType.SUPERGROUP, constants.ChatType.PRIVATE
        ]))
        application.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(self.handle_callback_inline_query))

        application.add_error_handler(error_handler)

        application.run_polling()
```

Как я себе это представлял: может быть как то можно создать свой handler, такой что бот понимает что это callback от юкассы и соответствующе себя ведет. Может быть есть и другие варианты. Подскажите пожалуйста.